# chrome driver reporting error in CentOS 7

Tags: linux, selenium-chromedriver

I have installed chrome driver in CentOS 7  by :

```
yum install nodejs
npm install chromedriver
```

Installed path :

```
/root/node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver
```

when i run :

```
[root@localhost chromedriver]# ./chromedriver
./chromedriver: error while loading shared libraries: libgconf-2.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 4):

You could install and check

```
sudo apt-get install libxi6 libgconf-2-4
```

Comment: This is for ubuntu

Comment: Yes, I was looking for ubuntu. Later i saw your post and found that you asked for centos. Anyways, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
yum install google-chrome-stable
```

this solves my request